# php Laravel - find element in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I want to use *foreach* to showing **orderId**s in my output.

Here is my code :

```
$orders = $results['result']['data'];
foreach ($orders as $key => $order)
{
     dd($order[$order]['orderId']);
}
```

here is *$orders* result :

```
  1 => array:3 [
    "orderId" => 4
    "orderTotalPrice" => 100
    }
    "resId" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "orderId" => 18
    "orderTotalPrice" => 100
    }
    "resId" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "orderId" => 34
    "orderTotalPrice" => 100
    }
    "resId" => 1
  ]
  4 => array:3 [
    "orderId" => 64
    "orderTotalPrice" => 100
    }
    "resId" => 1
  ]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: From where do those `}` come from?

Comment: @Rizier123 I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `foreach` you can do this:

```
$orderIDs = [];
foreach ($orders as $order){
     $orderIDs[] = $order['orderId'];
}
```

Or you can use the `pluck` method. It will retrieve all of the collection values for a given key:

```
collect($orders)->pluck('orderId')->all();
```

Comment: I don't think you need to declare the `$orderIDs = [];` prior to the `foreach` in this case...right?

Comment: You're def right ;) I don't know, maybe it's a habit from other languages !

Comment: Which makes it a tad cleaner solution (less code). Problem is, if you're looping through a lot of data, makes more sense to use `array_push` over your method. Better performance. If you needed to append a single item or two, this would make more sense. Either option should help the poster - +1 for the `collect()` method! :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
$order_ids = [];

foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    array_push($order_ids, $order['orderId']);
}

return $order_ids;
```

As per **@IsmailRBOUH**'s answer, use his solution if you're adding/pulling x-handful of data. If you're looping over a ***heavy amount*** of data, would be better (performance wise) to use `array_push`. But honestly, it's a fractional difference between them both. `$array[]` usually landing on top...

***PHP's website:***

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's
>   better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of
>   calling a function.

Answer (score -1):

"For showing orderId's in your output:"

```
$orders = $results['result']['data'];
foreach ($orders as $key => $order)
{
     echo $order['orderId'];
}
```